# HTC One Main Email doesn't show HTML

Tags: htc

My new HTC One is great, but I do have one weird question.  If there are pictures in a document it gives me an option to see the pictures, but it doesn't appear to show HTML on some e-mails.  Instead it shows the subject in a link, but if I go in my desktop it shows the html look and feel.  Any suggestions.